# Find specific color passage / spectra in image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, colors, getimagedata

I have an image like the example below...

[image: Example Image]

---> RESULT: `#ffdf00` => something like `30%`

... and I'd like to find the occurrence `(percentage)` of a specific color in the image (e.g. `#ffdf00 - yellow`), or even better I'd like to find the occurrence `(percentage)` of a specific color passage (e.g `#ffdf00 ---too---> #dabf09`) with simple javascript.

---

I've been already looking for javascript library's but all I found till' now is *extracting the main color of the image* like the plugins below:

- [getImageColor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-image-colors)
- [VibrantJS](https://jariz.github.io/vibrant.js/)

---

However I'm sure something like **color thief** can do the job, but I have no clue how to "SEARCH FOR SPECIFIC COLOR SPECTRA AND GET THE PERCENTAGE OCCURRENCE" (`#ffdf00 ---too---> #dabf09`), so I hope somebody can help me with my problem.

---

However, this is all what I got so far & now I've no clue how to continue...

```js
  function draw(img) {
      var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
      c.width = canvas.width = img.width;
      c.height = canvas.height = img.height;
      c.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
      c.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width , img.height);
      return c;
  }
  
  function getColors(c) {
      var col, colors = {};
      var pixels, r, g, b, a;
      r = g = b = a = 0;
      pixels = c.getImageData(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
      for (var i = 0, data = pixels.data; i < data.length; i += 4) {
          r = data[i];
          g = data[i + 1];
          b = data[i + 2];
          a = data[i + 3];
          if (a < (255 / 2))
              continue;
          col = rgbToHex(r, g, b);
          if (!colors[col])
              colors[col] = 0;
          colors[col]++;
      }
      return colors;
  }

  function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
      return ((r << 16) | (g << 8) | b).toString(16);
  }


  function pad(hex) {
      return ("000000" + hex).slice(-6);
  }
  var img=document.getElementById('img')
  var colors = getColors(draw(img));
```

```html
<img width=200 id='img'  src='https://s.aolcdn.com/hss/storage/midas/b386937631a1f03665c1d57289070898/203417456/simpsons.jpg'>
```

Thanks a million in advance, jonas

Comment: So you want to change the lightness of the color?

Comment: Ahm, tf? I'd like to 'Find specific color passage / spectra in image' rensvWal...

Comment: `if r>=da && r<=ff && g>=bf && g<=df && b>=0 &&b<=9 then inrange++` then at the end, the total pixels is `width*height` so the percentage is `inrange*100/total`